# how to make custom tier price in add product feature of magneto 2

Tags: magento2, module, custom, tiered-pricing

I want to make a tier price programmatically for quantity-based shipping prices
like the screenshot below, can anybody help me in developing this feature
[image]

Comment: I think after saving this data you need to develop a new shipping method and set a price based on your data.

Comment: @RutvikMonpara yeah but thats the step i develop this feature how can i make this shipping price(qty based) as shown in screenshot

Comment: You need to get all items in the current cart and based on that particular product add the price of shipping.